# load-grunt-config cannot read my custom config and call copy task from Gruntfile.js instead from my custom copy.js file

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to override copy task using load-grunt-config.

In my Gruntfile.js I have copy task that I want to override by custom copy task. 
In Gruntfile.js also I have this configuration for load-grunt-config:

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
  configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt/config'),
  jitGrunt: {
    customTasksDir: 'grunt/tasks'
  }
});
```

This is grunt/config/copy.js content:

```
module.exports = {
  main: {
    src: 'test/*',
    dest: 'copyTest'
};
```

And here is grunt/tasks/default.js content:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy:main']);
};
```

When I run the default task I got error:

```
Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
+ copy

Running "copy:main" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.main exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "copy.main" missing. Use --force to    continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your problem might have something to do with this issue - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/156 . I have created a minimal working example (with some changes to copy task and main Gruntfile), You can check it here - https://github.com/pra85/load-grunt-config-example . Hope it helps you with your problem

Comment: Try running your default task with the `--config-debug` option. You will then see the effective config grunt is using. Maybe the `load-grunt-config` plugin hasn't built the config the way you wanted it.